# how to add 5 icon in horizontal just like a tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

hello everyone i am making a template of the android app where i need to implement the icons in horizontal position.
can anyone tell me how to do this.

Here is the im using for the activity layout.

**Note: i am not using the tab layouts or fragment Tab host**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/dashboardgrey"
    android:id="@+id/imagebuttonDashboard"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/contactgrey"
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonContact"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/airplanegreen"
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonCampaingn"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="19dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/leadcaptureunselected"
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonLead"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/login_field_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bellgrey"
        android:id="@+id/imagebuttonnNotification"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the problem then?

Comment: check my answer,let me know is there any other issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonDashboard"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonContact"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonCampaingn"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonLead"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonnNotification"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: for diffrent screens of android what size of icon i need

Comment: in tablet the icon are strech